# How can I test a list of method calls in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Using this code I can print a list of the methods called in my test method:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock, call

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch(mymodule.DepObj)
    def mytest(self, mock_obj):
        mock_obj_ret = mock_obj.return_value # Object from constructor

        # Call test method

        callList = mock_obj_ret.method_calls
        self.assertEqual(5, len(callList))
        print(callList)
```

The output of `callList` is something like this:

```
[call.mymethod0(), call.mymethod1(MYARG1, key=val), call.mymethod2(myarg1, myarg2), call.mymethod3(myarg3), ...]
```

I need to test calls in `callList` for the names of the methods called (in their proper order) and the arguments used. How can I access the method names and parameters passed? I can't find it in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.method_calls).

Maybe something like this:

```
self.assertEqual("mymethod2", callList[1].name) # Doesn't work
```

I should note some the methods I want to test for are not mocks. For `print(vars(callList[1]))`, it gives:

```
{'_mock_name': None, '_mock_parent': None, '_mock_from_kall': True}
```

It is also unhelpful.

I can get the args and kwargs from a single call like this:

```
print(mock_obj_ret.method_calls[1].args)
print(mock_obj_ret.method_calls[1].kwargs)
```

But I still need to know how to get the *name* of the method called (as a string).

Answer (score 1):

#### About `method_calls`

`method_calls` is a list. Every element of the list is yet a list composed by 3 elements:

- first element (*index 0*) is a *string* which store the name of the method called
- second element (*index 1*) is a *tuple* which contains the arguments passed to the method called
- third element (*index 2*) is a *dictionary*; each element of the dictionary has the name of a method argument as its key, and the value of that argument as its value.

The third element of the `method_calls` list needs some explanation.

#### Third element of `method_calls`

In the example present in the question mymethod1() is called with 2 arguments: call.mymethod1(MYARG1, key=val). In this case the element of `method_calls` linked to mymethod1 is `method_calls[1]` because it is the second method called.
`method_calls[1]` has following values:

- method_calls[1][0] is equal to mymethod1
- method_calls[1][1] is equal to (MYARG1,)
- method_calls[1][2] is equal to {'key': val} => **this is a dictionary**

#### About the code of your question

To show the names the methods called, as well as their respective lists passed of arguments and keyword arguments (names and values):

```
for method_called_info in mock_obj_ret.method_calls:
    print(f"method name = {method_called_info[0]}")
    for arg in method_called_info[1]:
        print(arg)
    for k, v in method_called_info[2].items():
        print(f"{k}: {v}")
```

#### A trace to complete your tests

You can verify your code like this:

```
self.assertEqual("mymethod0", callList[0][0]) # for the name mymethod0

self.assertEqual("mymethod1", callList[1][0]) # for the name of mymethod1
self.assertEqual(MYARG1, callList[1][1][0]) # for the argument MYARG1 of mymethod1
kwargs = callList[1][2]
self.assertEqual("val", kwargs.get('key'))
...and so on
```